# Why is the net flux the same for both spheres?

Tags: electrostatics, field-theory, gauss-law

[image][image]

There are 2 spheres both of radius "r" and "R" respectively. Using Gauss' law to find the net flux from the surface, we use:

$$ = \frac{Q(charge \ enclosed)}{\epsilon_0} = E × ∮ds × cos(0°)$$

Here, when we use the first formula, we get the same answer for both of the spheres, but using the second formula, we get different values (which makes sense because the distance matters for the density of electrical field passing). So, **why is the flux from the first equation same for both the spheres**?

Comment: The differences in the density of electric field passing perfectly cancels the differences in radius.

Comment: A more precise way of stating what Nickolas has mentioned is that $|E(r)|\neq |E(R)|$ except when $r= R$.

Comment: @Triatticus Yes , It's true that the electric field won't be the the same at both the surfaces until their radius becomes equal. I browsed through different websites and it stated that tho both spheres have different surface area , the no. of electric field lines passing through one also passes through the another(same magnitude of charge placed inside them)  and thus the radius won't matters. But I didn't find it satisfactory because flux is all about the density of the field line through a unit area which cannot be the same for both?

Comment: No, the flux is not related to the density of lines. The electric field is. And it does decreases with radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The net flux through any closed surface surrounding a point charge $q_{in}$ is equal to $\frac{q_{in}}{\epsilon_0}$, and is independent of the shape of that surface. The following illustration should make things a bit clearer:

[image]

Clearly all the field lines passing through $S_1$ also pass through $S_2$ and $S_3$.
The electric flux is proportional to the *number* of electric field lines penetrating some surface.
As for the mathematical proof, as Triatticus has pointed out, the values of $E$ are not the same for both cases.

$$\phi_{E, 1} = \frac{q_{in}}{\epsilon_0} = E_1 \times4\pi r^2$$
With $E_1 = \frac{k_e.q}{r^2}$, we get: $$\phi_{E, 1} = 4\pi k_e.q_{in}$$

Similarly for the second case, with $E_2 = \frac{k_e.q}{R^2}$, we get: $$\phi_{E, 2} = 4\pi k_e.q_{in}$$
which are both equal to $\frac{q_{in}}{\epsilon_0}$

Hope this helps.

---

[Image source](https://www.deanza.edu/faculty/lunaeduardo/documents/ElectricFluxandGausssLaw.pdf)